# Activate iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone

We bought a used iPhone 4s and couldn't activate because it was still linked to the original owner. We contacted him and copied/pasted how to deactivate and deleted the phone from his account. He went into his account and it doesn't show up there any more. What do we do now?

Comment: Have you taken it to or talked to your service provider, if so, what did they say?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to activate the phone via iTunes.  Connect the phone via USB to your computer and launch iTunes. It should guide you automatically.